# Resolve function does not resolve component data before the component ngOnInit function is invoked

Tags: angular, resolve, resolver, angular4-router

I have a URL that is something like this:

`base_path/some_path?elementId=33203`

Basically, a user can and generally navigates to this path by pasting the above link in the browser. I **need to load the data for this component before the component** so I started reading up on the Angular routing tutorial, specifically, the resolver services that aim to achieve the exact quandry I possess. So I created a resolver service such as:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<SomeObject> {
    let loanId = route.queryParams['elementId'];

    if (isNil(loanId)) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.service.getElementById(elementId)
      .subscribe(response => {
    //response is JSON
          return Observable.of(response);
        }
        else {
          return null;
        }
      });
  }
```

This resolve class is now added to the app.routing.module.ts like:

```
{ path: 'base_path/some_path', component: SomeComponent,
resolve : {
  someObject: SomeObjectResolver
}
```

}

And make the corresponding changes in my component.ts file, such as:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.route.data.subscribe((data: { someObject: SomeObject}) => {

     });

}
```

I setup debug breakpoints in the resolver and component file. When I visit the URI: `base_path/some_path?elementId=33203`, it hits the resolver first, but since the resolver invokes the service (which in turn invokes an ajax call to the server fetch data), it then simply proceeds to the component, and invokes the ngOnInit function, tryin to invoke the subscribe function on (data: { someObject: SomeObject})

However, someObject is not yet available, so it throws an error and redirects.

What am I missing? Isn't the resolve function supposed to explicitly load the data for it's component before it is invoked?

Comment: You need to actually *return the observable* for it to work; `resolve` currently *doesn't* return `Observable<SomeObject>`, I'm surprised the compiler hasn't told you that.

Comment: why don't you return the observable directly instead of subcribing to it and then return a new observable?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: this is not returning an Observable?   return Observable.of(response);

Comment: It's returning it *from that callback*. But that *isn't* the return value of `resolve`.

Comment: let me correct, the return value is the the service callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return an Observable, you don't need to subscribe to it and then return a new observable

```ts
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<SomeObject> {
  let loanId = route.queryParams['elementId'];

  if (isNil(loanId)) {
    return Observable.of(null);
  }
  return this.service.getElementById(elementId);
}
```

Comment: yeah, actually it does have return on this.service, I missed that

Comment: can you provide the service function in your code please?

Comment: It basically returns an Observable<Response>